# How to parse JSON and get particular values using objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I am trying to get particular datas from below `JSON` and store into `NSMutableArray` for loading `tableview`. Now The problem is I don't know how to get `"names and grade values"` and want to store into `NSMutableArray` for `tableview` listing purpose.

```
response {

   Private { 

          0 = { 
                  name : nanci,
                  grade : A
              };  
          1 = { 
                  name : nanci,
                  grade : B
              };  
          }
   Public { 

          0 = { 
                  name : doly,
                  grade : A
              };  
          1 = { 
                  name : mali,
                  grade : B
              };  
            }
         }
```

My Tableview looks below

```
----------------------------------
     name           grade
----------------------------------
     doly               A
----------------------------------
```

Please help me how to get values from JSON and store into `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this way to get data from json response

```
NSMutableDictionary *yourJsonData = yourjsonresponsedata;
    // get private key data
    for (int i=0; i<[[[yourJsonData objectForKey:@"Private"] allKeys] count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"name = %@",[[[yourJsonData objectForKey:@"Private"] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]] objectForKey:@"name"]);
        NSLog(@"Grade = %@",[[[yourJsonData objectForKey:@"Private"] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]] objectForKey:@"grade"]);
    }
```

Comment: Awesome @Dharmesh...Can I store both values into Single NSMUtableArray and want to get both private and public. Actually into my tableview I will create two section one for private another one for public.

Comment: No you store different array because you use two section (private, public) so first section number of row count data first array and another array data for second section. @SteaveJobs

Comment: For example If I use search..can I do by both array?

Comment: yes if you use two section for table then use two array. @SteaveJobs

Comment: And your json formate is complicated please use this json formate so easy way to get data. `{
"Private" :[
        {
            "name" : "nanci",
            "grade" : "A"
        },
        {
            "name" : "nanci",
            "grade" : "B"
        }
    ],
"Public" :[
        {
            "name" : "nanci",
            "grade" : "A"
        },
        {
            "name" : "nanci",
            "grade" : "B"
        }
    ]
}` @SteaveJobs

Comment: Sure Thank you! but I cant chage that one I am getting from another environments!